# Pandas indexing and accessing columns by names

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe, pandas

I am trying to access pandas dataframe by column names after indexing the df with a specific column and it returns incorrect column values.

```
import pandas as pd
rs =pd.read_csv('rs.txt', header="infer", sep="\t",  names=['id', 'exp','fov','cycle', 'color', 'values'], index_col=2)

rs.cycle.head()
```

I am indexing the df here with 'fov' and I want to access the 'cycle' column, it gives me the color column instead. I think I am missing something here?

---

EDIT
The first few lines of the input file are:

```
6 3 1 G 0.96593 
6 3 1 O 0.88007 
6 3 1 R 0.94305 
6 3 2 B 0.90554 
6 3 2 G 0.93146
```

Comment: Can you please post the first few lines of `rs.txt`?

Comment: @mbatchkarov, Here are few lines from rs.txt 
`    6 3 1 G 0.96593 
    6 3 1 O 0.88007 
    6 3 1 R 0.94305 
    6 3 2 B 0.90554 
    6 3 2 G 0.93146`

Comment: I added the sample data to your original question. Can you check if I've put the line breaks at the right places?

Comment: @mbatchkarov, yes thanks, this is the correct format, it wouldn't let me post in the above format after 5 edits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem arises because your data file has 5 columns and your `names` list has 6 elements. To verify, check the first few values in the `id` column- these will all be set to `6` if I am right. The First few items in the `exp` column will have the value `3`.

To fix this, read your input file like so:

```
rs =pd.read_csv('rs.txt', header="infer", sep="\t",  names=['exp','fov','cycle', 'color', 'values'], index_col=2
```

Pandas will automatically insert row identifiers.

Comment: there are in fact 6 columns in the file, the first column is empty corresponding to 'id' for downstream purposes. I missed pointing that in my earlier comment.

Comment: I still think pandas is not correctly handling your empty column and you end up with either with 5 columns, or with 6 columns, but shifted one to the left. Please post the output of `print rs.columns` and `print rs`

Comment: I identified the problem, there was an invisible tab at the end of the file that was causing this problem. I added a place holder in the names for the last tab and it works as expected now. Thanks for your suggestions :).